# I'm trying to highlight a string in some places of my document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to highlight my client's name in some places in the document using a macro. There are some places where the name should be highlighted and some places where it should not.

I've tried moving around the wdNoHighlight code to different locations without any luck; wherever I seem to put it, I get the same result: the entire paragraph after the name is highlighted.

'''

```
ClientName = "Barry Allen"
Call HighlightName(ClientName)
Selection.TypeText Text:="Some more text after the client's name, which I don't want to be highlighted"
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeText Text:="This text will not be highlighted"

Sub HighlightName(NametoHighlight)
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(NametoHighlight), 
Extend:=wdExtend
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
End Sub
```

'''

My code works when the name is in its own paragraph, but when the name is part of a paragraph, the entire paragraph that is after the name is highlighted, but I only want the name highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it work. You insert a paragraph and then backspace to get rid of the extra paragraph. Not the most elegant solution, but it does what I need it to do. The code I added to the bottom of the HighlightName Sub was:

```
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.TypeBackspace
```

If anyone has a more elegant solution, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

For instance:

```
Sub Demo()
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
Const ClientName As String = "Barry Allen"
With Selection
  .Text = "Some text before the client's name" & ClientName & " some more text after the client's name" & vbCr & "Next paragraph"
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = ClientName
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Replacement.Highlight = True
    .Format = True
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End With
End Sub
```